# Error building grails app

Tags: java, grails, version

I have an **Java** version **1.6.0_37** and **Grails 1.3.9**. When building my app I get a following error:

```
Compilation error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/SpringSecurityUtils : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I've found out that the code `51` means a conflict with Java version 1.7. But I removed that Java version.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile the `org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/SpringSecurityUtils` class under JDK 1.6. It's source can be found [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core).